# bootstrap modal is appearing slow on samsung galaxy z fold 6

Tags: performance, rendering

The modal opens quickly on devices from other brands, but it does not open quickly on the Samsung Galaxy Z Fold 6.

I am currently using nextJS with Redux toolkit, and when I click on an item, multiple values are being set in the Redux state through dispatch.

This functionality works well on other devices, but there seems to be a performance issue specifically on the Samsung Galaxy Z Fold 6. I am aiming to improve the speed at which the modal appears on this device.